# If operators $A$ and $B$ commute and $B$ and $C$ commute, do $A$ and $C$ necessarily commute?

Tags: linear-algebra

I came across the following statement:

> If $A$ and $B$ commute and $B$ and $C$ commute, do $A$ and $C$ necessarily commute? Prove or disprove.

Help.

Comment: "an operator identity" is a pointless title. please give your questions informative titles.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Choose $B$ as the identity operator and $A$ and $C$ any operators that don't commute.

Comment: Alternatively, take $B=0$.

Comment: Good idea. I didn't think of that.